Stream data in real time using EventSource from Dash Extensions
I am looking at this example:
https://www.dash-extensions.com/components/event_source
which seems like an elegant way to send data from a device to a client (to either store, plot, or perform other actions). The issue, however, is that the data is being stored at http://127.0.0.1:5000/random_data, and this file seems to grow indefinitely. Assuming the device sends 100,000 new values per second, the file could grow to several hundred megabytes within an hour (assuming 8 bits per value).
Is there a way to prevent this file from growing excessively? Or is EventSource a non-optimal way to stream lots of data ?
